# Access model in view model in Aurelia Compose

Tags: javascript, aurelia

So according to the heading **Dynamically Render UI into the DOM based on Data** [here](http://aurelia.io/docs.html#/aurelia/framework/1.0.0-beta.1.2.4/doc/article/cheat-sheet/6) (scroll down a bit).

```
<template repeat.for="item of items">
    <compose model.bind="item" view-model="widgets/${item.type}"></compose>
</template>
```

If you take it more simply:

```
<compose model.bind="item" view-model="itemViewModel.js"></compose>
```

If I have an `itemViewModel.html` and a `itemViewModel.js`, they both get successfully loaded. However, how do you access the bound model in the `itemViewModel.js`?

I tried using the `bindable`.

```
import {bindable, bindingMode} from 'aurelia-framework';

export class ItemViewModel {
    @bindable model;

    constructor() {
        console.log("using bindable", this);
    }
}
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`<compose model.bind="item"` will call a method `activate(model)` in your viewmodel and give you the `item`.

```
// the model received here is the *item* from the above <compose
activate(model){
   this.model = model;
}
```

If you want to pass multiple models in the bind you can do

```
<compose model.bind="{item: item, value: value}"
```

Then you get:

```
activate(model){
    this.item = model.item;
    this.value = model.value;
}
```

Comment: @Corneliu and would I be able to listen to changes of the model.value? Sort of like using valueChanged()? If not how can I do that?